SSL issue with a Domain-named GCP bucket
I'm facing an SSL issue with a Domain-named GCP bucket - here's the situation:
I have created three GCP buckets:
media.dev.example.com
media.qa.example.com
media.example.com
Where example.com is my domain
I've mapped these buckets using CNAMEs pointing to c.storage.googleapis.com. My domain has a valid SSL certificate, but when I access these URLs or any images within the buckets, they are served over HTTP and show as "Not Secure."
I expected the content to be served securely over HTTPS, but that's not happening. I'm not sure if I've missed a step or if there's something specific to Google Cloud Storage or the CNAME setup that needs attention.
Has anyone encountered this issue before or know how to fix it? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

You cannot without using a Load-balancer.
Cloud Storage doesn't support custom domains with TLS.
See Hosting a static website (with an external load-balancer) for a tutorial on how to do this.
